# Getting error when using addTo in bootstrap to preload db

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following classes: SAMPLE_TYPE and SAMPLE_PARAMETER. Each sample can have many parameters. In my bootstrap I have created a parameter and the sample:

```
 def r = new SampleParameter(name: "Color", value:"Red").save(failOnError: true)
 def b = new SampleType(sampleName: "Blood")
        .addToSampleType(r)
        .save(failOnError: true)
```

I keep getting an error 'no signature of method com.SampleType.addToSampleType() is applicable for argument types

I just want to add a parameter to a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looks to me like you're trying to add a SampleParameter (variable named r) as a SampleType.  Maybe the method should be `.addToSampleParameter(r)`?  If that's not the case can you please post a copy of your domian classes?

Comment: @universitas it would be much better to edit your question and paste it there

Comment: @tim_yates thanks for the tip. @Jarred Olson it seems to work when I use this statement: `  b.addToSampleParameters(r).save()` - However if I add it through the scaffolding, I can see the name and value columns, but when I add via bootstrap I only get value. Any idea why?